# How to add String - Integer pair inside Bundle?

Tags: android, bundle

I have used like this but it is not working.
I want to store as String as key and Integer as value and by invoking getInt() I should get that Integer values, which can use to make call dynamically, according to the click on list items. I have posted my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView emrcontact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    emrcontact=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final String[] emergency={"Local Police", "Fire Service", "Ambulance", "Blood Bank", "Womens Helpline", "Child Helpline", "Indian Railways"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,emergency);
    emrcontact.setAdapter(adapter);





    emrcontact.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {

            Bundle dataBundle=new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("Local Police",100);
            dataBundle.putInt("Fire Service",101);
            dataBundle.putInt("Ambulance",102);
            dataBundle.putInt("Blood Bank",104);
            dataBundle.putInt("Womens Helpline",181);
            dataBundle.putInt("Child Helpline",1098);
            dataBundle.putInt("Indian Railways",1322);
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
            dataIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);

            Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();

            switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Local Police"));
                }
                break;

            case 1:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Fire Service"));
                }
                break;

            case 2:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Ambulance"));
                }
                break;

            case 3:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Blood Bank"));
                }
                break;

            case 4:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Womens Helpline"));
                }
                break;

            case 5:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Child Helpline"));
                }
                break;

            case 6:

                if(b!=null) 
                {
                callToemrcontact(b.getInt("Indian Railways"));
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }


        }
    });




}
void callToemrcontact(int i)
{
     Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"i"));
     startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

logcat result is as below:

```
10-08 06:20:25.407: E/Trace(805): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-08 06:20:25.967: D/dalvikvm(805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 8% free 2442K/2640K, paused 44ms, total 52ms
10-08 06:20:26.017: I/dalvikvm-heap(805): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.767MB for 2359312-byte allocation
10-08 06:20:26.107: D/dalvikvm(805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 4743K/4948K, paused 83ms, total 83ms
10-08 06:20:26.227: D/dalvikvm(805): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4743K/4948K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 119ms
10-08 06:20:26.467: D/dalvikvm(805): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2305K, 45% free 3115K/5616K, paused 20ms+25ms, total 79ms
10-08 06:20:26.737: D/libEGL(805): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-08 06:20:26.747: D/(805): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a148e68, tid 805
10-08 06:20:26.777: D/libEGL(805): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-08 06:20:26.797: D/libEGL(805): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
10-08 06:20:26.877: W/EGL_emulation(805): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-08 06:20:26.897: D/OpenGLRenderer(805): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: are you using above code in same activity?

Comment: if you are passing data between fragments use bundle. If your are passing data between Activities send Intents.

Comment: @KaranMer Ya I am using those codes in the same activity.

Comment: @war_Hero I am using those in the same activity. I am a beginner to Android applications dev. So I don't know about fragments. I have posted the code you can get about my requirement from there of using Bundle.

Comment: In intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"i"));,
why is the i in quotes?

Comment: @chitti We have to pass the number to make call and that should be as String.  i.e. Uri.parse(String uriString)

Comment: But if you put the i in quotes, the variable i is never used. It is treated as the string "i", which has nothing to do with your integer.
Uri.parse("tel:" + i) is what you want. When you concatenate a string and integer, java automatically treats the whole entity as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like this:

```
dataBundle.putString("Ambulance",String.valueOf(YourInt));
....
....
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String temp = b.getString("Ambulance");

int myInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```

Comment: Bundle has a putInt method, which is more suitable for this need. This method works, but involves unnecessary conversions.

Comment: @chitti Can you please answer the question in some more details.

Comment: Check out the answer by war_Hero.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it like this
In Fragment A

```
        `Bundle dataBundle=new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putInt("Local Police",100);
        dataBundle.putInt("Fire Service",101);`
```

and before doing fragment transaction ensure you pass your bundle to **fragment.setArguments(bundle)**.
In Fragment B

```
        `Bundle dataBundle=getArguments();
        dataBundle.getInt("Local Police");
        dataBundle.getInt("Fire Service");`
```

Comment: Can you please tell me about the fragments? I mean how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `dataBundle` variable instead of `b`. `b=getIntent().getExtras()` will give you bundle from intent received by mainactivity not your created bundle

Comment: Now I replaced b with dataBundle. But still it is not working. My requirement is to store the String and Integer in Bundle as Key and Value pair and by invoking getInt() I should get that Integer values, which can use to make call dynamically, according to the click on list items.

Comment: call getInt as follows `dataBundle.getInt("Local Police",0);`

Comment: I am calling like dataBundle.getInt("Local Police"). getInt() will take only one argument right? i.e. "String Key"

Comment: it was by mistake. now try calling getint as follow `dataBundle.getInt("Local Police");` tell what are you getting

Comment: Same not getting any response. I am using the Bundle in the same activity so do I need to use Intent object? Only Bundle dataBundle =new Bundle(); dataBundle.putInt("A", 1); int i=dataBundle.getInt("A"); will it do my work?

Comment: pass your bundle object in below method and check whether you are getting values or not `public static String bundle2string(Bundle bundle) {
  if (bundle == null) {
   return null;
  }
  String string = "Bundle{";
  for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
   string += " " + key + " => " + bundle.get(key) + ";";
  }
  string += " }Bundle";
  return string;
 }` method will return the string so Log the return value